# modules not found in standalone puppet

Tags: puppet

I am starting the journey with Puppet.

I have installed stand-alone puppet on RHEL 6.0 (NO master/agent, just stand-alone)

Puppet version is 4.5.2

I have created a module `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/common/manifests/init.pp` as

```
class user {
  user { 'wasadmin':
    ensure => present,
    comment => 'wasadmin user',
    home => '/home/wasadmin',
    managehome => true
  }
}
```

my `site.pp` is here as `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp`

```
node "CI-TEST-POC" {
   include user
}

modulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

when I execute with and without `--modulepath`, I am still getting the same error

```
root@CI-TEST-POC manifests# puppet apply site.pp
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::user for ci-test-poc.corp.aal.au at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2:4 on node ci-test-poc.corp.aal.au

root@CI-TEST-POC manifests# puppet apply site.pp --modulepath ../modules
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::user for ci-test-poc.corp.aal.au at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2:4 on node ci-test-poc.corp.aal.au
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have created a module /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/common/manifests/init.pp as
>
> `class user {`

The problem lies here, as Puppet requires that the layout of manifests matches the name of the classes/defines within them to help it quickly and correctly find the right file.

For your `user` class, it should be defined in `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/user/manifests/init.pp`.

Comment: Hi m0dlf, that worked like a charm! Good point to learn as well. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.